# Running another instance of the same program with a goroutine?

Tags: multithreading, go, goroutine

Is it an acceptable practice to run multiple instances of the same go program using goroutines, like running go main()?

If so, is it possible to modify arguments sent to the goroutine (or os.Args[]) such that the main() function does not create an infinite number of goroutines? 
The goroutines should then be able to communicate with each other via channels. I understand that goroutines share the same memory space but have separate stacks, so this could cause some race condition issues.

Or, perhaps, this is an improper use of Goroutines and I should just stick to exec.Command() to execute another instance of the executable, and have those instances communicate via a JSON-RPC.

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Why do you need to run multiple instances of your program?

Comment: i think Supervisor will be a better choice.

Comment: communicate via gRPC maybe https://grpc.io/

Comment: @tkausl basically it's a backend that needs to spawn multiple instances of itself to handle load. The more that I think about it, however, I realize that exec.Command('./myprogram', 'someargs') is probably a better choice in my case. I could then use websockets or HTTP/RPC for the processes to communicate with eachother rather than channels (but I still think channels will be faster).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you are understanding how a *goroutine* works here. Think of it like a virtual thread, as it is pretty much Go's alternative to threads in practice. When you call `go foo()` you are spawning a goroutine (or virtual thread) within your executable same as you would a thread in other languages, not a separate process as an exec or syscall.ForkExec().

The proper practice in Go is to stick with a single process and use goroutines for concurrent responsibilities. For example, if you are writing your own port listener and want several iterations to each listen on a different port, your outline might be:

```
func APIHandler(port int) {
    // do stuff
}

func main() {
    go APIHandler(80)
    go APIHandler(81)
    go APIHandler(82)

    // sync.WaitGroup, or maybe wait on an error chan
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I understand how goroutines work, I'm just asking if I can spawn multiple instances of the main() goroutine concurrently that can interact with each other. For example, what happens if I run `go main()`? Does Go allow that?

Comment: I don't think you can call main() function

Comment: I would not call it. In practice, I would follow the model in the example I gave for anything more than a short linear tool. Most services, especially when unit tested, I put the meat in a separate Run() function and main() just calls that and little else.

Comment: Yeah any code that calls `main()` should not survive code review. There is absolutely no reason to choose that over the answer given here, and many reasons not to.